# Google Charts - Error with loader.js busy on line 138

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I am building a sample slide application using Google Charts API, each slide have some different graphics.

But, when pass some time running on a raspberry, the browser (Mozilla) shows the next error:

[image]

The loader.js file was on the gstatic.com, but I have downloaded it to my host and the error persists. Someone can help me?

**more informations:**
Each slide is loaded individually using Ajax and PHP. The script loads the graphic codes each time Ajax loads, but I call the `google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});` method one time on my host page.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error message today as well:

> Warning: Unresponsive script
>
> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
>
> Script: https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js line 138 > eval:187

While I can't see the rest of your code to confirm that it's occurring for the exact same reason, I would recommend **checking the ID of the container in which you're drawing your chart**.

For example, here was my JavaScript code with the problematic line:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
```

And here was my HTML:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Simply using the name `chart` as an ID for the chart container element threw loader.js into an infinite loop.